# how do I resolve an error occured during execution of LOC, how to use nb_epoch in writing code

Tags: python

I am executing code to learn deep learning, I am new in this, I am executing code on Colab while executing the code

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=10, nb_epoch=100)
```

I got error

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> ----> 1 model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=10, nb_epoch=100)
> 2
>
> TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nb_epoch'

can anybody tell me why this error occured.

Comment: searching for `fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nb_epoch'` lead to (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64180817/typeerror-fit-generator-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-nb-val-samples) - see Kalana's answer: use `epochs` instead of _epoch_.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what library you are using but assuming you are using tf.keras the parameter is called `epochs` not `nb_epoch`: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit